# firebase/firestore save user to collection

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am trying to save a user to a collection in my Firestore. It seems that the users are being created, I can see them in the `Authentication` tab, however they are not saving to my collection inside my firestore. There doesn't seem to be any errors inside my console either. I've been struggling with this for a couple hours now and i'm not even sure how to debug this.

```
export const authMethods = {
  signup: (email, password, setErrors, setToken) => {
    firebase
      .auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      // make res asynchronous so that we can make grab the token before saving it.
      .then(async res => {
        const token = await Object.entries(res.user)[5][1].b
        // set token to localStorage
        await localStorage.setItem('token', token)
        // grab token from local storage and set to state.
        setToken(window.localStorage.token)
        const userUid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
        const db = firebase.firestore()
        db.collection('/users')
          .doc(userUid)
          .set({
            email,
            password,
          })
        console.log(res)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        setErrors(prev => [...prev, err.message])
      })
  },
 ....
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You're ignoring the promise returned by `db.collection().doc().set()`.  It could be failing and you'd never know.

Comment: What do you mean? Could you show me an example please?

Comment: You're already handling a promise returned by `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`.  Do the same thing with `set()`.  This is standard JavaScript.

Comment: Change your part `db.collection('/users').doc(userUid).set({email,password,})` to something like this `db.collection('/users').doc(userUid).set({email,password,}).then().catch((err) => console.log(err))`, so you will handle your promise and check if there is any errors on it.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing in the end, the error was from database security rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `await` from `localStorage.setItem` it isn't an asynchronous function.

You'll also need to add await to `db.collection("/users").doc(userUid)`

---

This is another approach that you could do. Let a cloud function handle that for you.

Whenever a user is created the following function is triggered.

```
export const onUserCreate = functions.auth
  .user()
  .onCreate(async (user, context) => {
    await admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(user.uid).set({
      id: user.uid,
      emailAddress: user.email,
      verified: user.emailVerified,
    });
  });
```

If you need more information about cloud functions read the following.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started